# Where can one get a large .bin opening book?

Tags: opening, scid

SCID uses .bin files as opening book format, but the opening books it has available on its site are rather small in size. Is there a better place to get larger .bin opening books? Alternatively, does SCID allow taking a large database, and turning that into an opening book? Polyglot uses pgn's, which probably won't work for building truly large .bin books.

Comment: .bin is kind of like .dat or .data in that they just specify that they are data, as apposed to text or an image or other portable format... your bin file would have to be specifically a SCIC .bin file.

Comment: When you get this .bin file, how do you get it into SCID?

Answer (score 3):

The [Stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/download/) opening book works with scid, follow the directions there to use it with the engine.  To use it in scid itself copy the `book.bin` file to the same location you have all your other scid opening books. I hope you have [scidvspc](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net) and not the original...

Comment: Why do you recommend scidvspc?